# Configuring Compiz Grid?

Tags: compiz, window-manager

Apparently there is a way to get an *Areo Snap* feature with the *Grid* plugin for Compiz. I've downloaded the advanced configuration files and have selected the plugin in the Compiz configuration - even re-mapped the keys because I don't have a numpad. Regardless of what I do, I can't get it to work, either by dragging the windows or using the assigned keys.

Is there something I need to do in addition to these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aero snap isn't available for Compiz 0.8.6 (assuming that you've installed the current stable 10.10), so with the Grid plugin you can only use keyboard shortcuts. [Ctrl+Alt+Num]

Please wait until Compiz 0.9 is shipped with Ubuntu 11.04 to be able to use it, normally I would say install it yourself but you're a 3 days old ubuntu user :P.

Comment: I've been using Ubuntu for years and I still don't feel comfortable installing a newer Compiz.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I can't vote you up yet, but as soon as I can I will. Do you have an alternative in order to achieve the same effect?

Comment: @Firefeather it's not worth it, I tested it.

Comment: @Alec Here's a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOAsNyRE7k4

Comment: L.: Thanks for the warning. I've been getting tempted to try it. +1